# gnome-keyring not working with svn 1.9

Tags: svn, centos, gnome

I am using WANdisco subversion 1.9.2 via command line on CentOS 6.4.
I'd like to store passwords for http access of repositories encrypted via gnome-keyring.

I can change the configuration in ~/.subversion/ to store passwords un-encrypted, but trying to store them encrypted in gnome-keyring doesn't work. svn is not even asking for the keyring password.

Could it be because of an incompatibility of gnome 2.28.2 with svn 1.9.2 ?
What API does svn use to talk to the keyring? What environment variables need to be set?

Thanks!

```
[abc@def ~]$ env |grep KEYRING
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET=/tmp/keyring-ic4aSc/socket
```

Note that there is no `GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL` or `GNOME_KEYRING_PID` variable set.

```
[abc@def ~]$ env |grep DBUS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-TuG0dBuJRX,guid=4eb7f485c19be9c8fd5801c600238bde


[abc@def ~]$ svn --version
svn, version 1.9.2 (r1703836)
   compiled Nov  2 2015, 10:52:33 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2015 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.7
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

The following authentication credential caches are available:

* Plaintext cache in /home/abc/.subversion
* Gnome Keyring
* GPG-Agent
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config), make sure that you've set `password-stores` option to `gnome-keyring`.

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. GPG-Agent is working, but gnome-keyring is not. Is there a way to debug this issue?

Comment: I'd ask at users@ subversion mailing list http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html